# How to use stack bench

Tags: haskell, benchmarking, haskell-stack

I've been playing around with using stack for a little haskell application, so far I have been able to build and test fine and was interested in looking at performance so tried `stack bench` however this is all that seems to happen:

```
c:\Users\jk\projects\foo>stack bench
stack bench
```

I don't think it can have done anything? My application does not appear to have run. Presuembly there is some configuration I am missing?

Comment: Have you configured [cabal benchmarks](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#benchmarks)?

Comment: no, in fact I've done very little with the cabal file as I used stack new to create the project which seems to create build and test targets ... but not bench

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stack bench` will run any benchmark suites defined in your `foo.cabal` file.  Without seeing it it's hard to say more, note though that you can run with `-v` to get more output.

From what I see above however I guess you don't have defined any benchmarks so `stack bench` does nothing because there is nothing to do :)