# How to use stack bench?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-criterion

Just tried to run the benchmarks on a project that I have converted from cabal to stack. Running `stack bench` just prints out `project-name-version: benchmarks` with no further output. Do I have to pass additional flags to stack to see the criterion output?

benchmark section for reference:

```
benchmark mainbench
  type:             exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:   src, bench
  main-is:          MainBench.hs
  build-depends:    base,
                    vector,
                    linear,
                    hmatrix,
                    hmatrix-gsl,
                    criterion,
                    random,
                    MonadRandom
  ghc-options:      -Wall
                    -O2
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

Edit: this is on `stack-0.1.6.0`

(This is no duplicate of [How to use stack bench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998500/how-to-use-stack-bench) :) )

Answer (score 3):

I think there is something amiss with your setup. This is typical output (project name is `bennie`, benchmark name is `bennie-mark`):

```
$ stack bench
bennie-0.1.0.0: benchmarks
Running 1 benchmarks...
Benchmark bennie-mark: RUNNING...
... output of bennie-mark ...
Benchmark bennie-mark: FINISH
```

This is with stack-0.1.6.0. Perhaps try upgrading/reinstalling stack.
Maybe try `stack -v bench`.

Comment: I tried `-v` this gives pages of output from stack, but then hides the output from criterion/the program. This is on stack 0.1.6.0 too.

Comment: Did you by chance setup the benchmark section in the cabal file differently?

Comment: This is the cabal file I used: http://lpaste.net/3673762003903578112 The program beanie-mark simply does a `putStrLn "blah"`, but you should still see all of the surrounding output.